# 3 simple htaccess tasks, so why am I looping?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to accomplish 3 fairly standard url mods in my htaccess file, but unfortunately I am getting thrown in a loop.  What am I doing wrong?

```
# force a trailing slash
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)$ /profile/$1/ [R=301,L]

# check for trailing parameters
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$

# put it all together
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)/$ /profile/index.php?username=$1&%1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern of your first rule, `^profile/([^/]+)$`, does also match the destination of your second rule, `profile/index.php`.

You could simply exclude that file with an additional `RewriteCond` for the first rule:

```
RewriteCond $1 !=index.php
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)$ /profile/$1/ [R=301,L]
```